# Log4j doesn't display process PID

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I just installed and configured log4j.
It works, but doesn't show process PID, instead prints `${sys:PID}` instead of, for example, 12941.
My **log4j-config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout
                    disableAnsi="false"
                    pattern="%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}} %highlight{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=green, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue} %style{${sys:PID}}{magenta} --- [%15.15t] %style{%-40.40C{1.}}{cyan} : %m%n%ex"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And
[**console output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pCcK.png)

So, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `sys:PID` with `%pid` and it started working.
I took that from [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15426)